# Android ListActivity ListView setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to access to the data that is present in my `Cursor` on a `ListView`; however the parameter onSetItemClickListener `long id` is always 0.

How can I do that, without using the position (because my `Cursor` doesn't represent the database directly; it is a query).

Comment: What other you mean to access in your cursor? That cursor contains data from your query nothing else.

Comment: I want to read information from the current selected line on the list view

Answer (score 0):

reading that you are working with a database I suppose that you are filling the `ListView` with a custom Adapter you created with what you want to show, and a it's corresponding XML to represent each custom row with the data you are bringing back.

I faced something similar wanting to return the Ids of clicked element, what I did was in the XML of the row add an invisible `TextView`.

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dip"
   android:id="@+id/post_Id"
   android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

and then I just access that value on the click event doing the following:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   int id = Integer.valueOf(((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_Id)).getText().toString());
   // THE REST OF THE CODE GOES HERE
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: yeah, it should work, but there is no standard way to do this?